# Is there a function to ask for input till a value is in a particular list?

Tags: python

Is there a way to ask for an input till the input is in the four options given for e.g.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
number = input('number: ')
```

In this example, I want it to input till the number is not in the list.
I know we can do it like this

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
while True:
    number = input('Number: ')
   if number in list:
       break
   else:
       pass
```

But, I want a shorter code as it is too tedious if there are multiple inputs.

Comment: When it's tedious, write a function to do it.  Clearly, there would not be a standard library routine for something so special purpose.  `input` is not all that common in production scripts.  Input more often comes from the command line.  And you understand that the `else:` / `pass` sequence is totally unnecessary, right?

Comment: else:pass was just added so that you can understand it. Actually, I add a print statement for that like print('It is not a valid number') etc.

Answer (score 2):

The shorter but practically the same code would be:

```
number=0
while number not in list:
    number = int(nput('Number: '))
```

Though please do not name the variable `list` as it is already a keyword

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the else/pass and you need to cast the input to integer

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

while True:
    number = int(input("give number"))

    if number in list:
        break

print(number)
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add int. And as I told earlier else:pass was just added so that you can understand it. Actually, I add a print statement for that like print('It is not a valid number') etc.